# Cartthrob Vault payments with Stripe

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway, stripe

I have tried http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/authorize_later_with_vaults/index.html with stripe but I get the error `The card object must have a value for 'number'.` when trying to authoirize as the example, im assuming because the `{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}` is still looking for the credit card information rather than just the token to authorise payment?

Any help on how I can fix this? I used Cartthrob and stripe becasue of this feature to charge later if product becomes available, but not working right now.